# `UnexpectedAlertOpenError` in Selenium Webdriver on Node.js is present even after dismissing the alert

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumberjs

I am using Cucumber.js and Selenium Webdriver JS in a Node.js environment, using Firefox as my browser.

I am trying to test a page that shows an alert on load. I have created a Cucumber step to dismiss the alert box which appears to work (visibly, the alert disappears) but I still get the error:

```
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: Dismissed user prompt dialog: Some alert text...
```

I have tried many different ways of getting around this but have had no success.

I have tried:

Setting an option when I build the browser:

```
let options = new firefox.Options();
options.setAlertBehavior(UserPromptHandeler, 'dismiss');
this.driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();
```

Dismissing it in a Cucumber step:

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});
```

And this way (as per Selenium docs):

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent());
    let alert = await this.driver.switchTo().alert();
    await alert.dismiss();
});
```

I've also tried waiting before dismissing:

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 3000 });
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});
```

And

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.sleep(3000);
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});
```

But no matter what I do I always get same error as above on the "When I dismiss the alert" step.

Would anyone know what I need to do to solve this error?

My full code:

```
const { When, Then, Given } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const { Builder, By, until, Key } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Options } = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const { UserPromptHandeler } = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities');

Given('I am on the branch locator page', async function () {
    let options = new firefox.Options();
        //options.setAlertBehavior(UserPromptHandeler, 'dismiss');
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(options)
        .build();
    
    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('h1')));

    await this.driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com');    
});

 When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.sleep(3000);
    //await this.driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 3000 });
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
    // await this.driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent());
    // let alert = await this.driver.switchTo().alert();
    // await alert.dismiss();
});

Then('I click the radio button', async function() {
    await this.driver.findElement(By.id('option2')).click();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just let the test fail so someone can fix the frontend?

Comment: @pguardiario how do you mean? The front end is fine. The issue is I cannot test other things because of this Selenium error.

Comment: I'm saying if selenium can't get past that it's probably something that's affecting normal users too. Also, "a page that shows an alert on load" sounds strange to me, maybe just don't do that.

Comment: You want to set the unexpectedPromptBehaviour of the driver... ex: options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'dismiss')  I believe the default behavior is DISMISS AND NOTIFY... the notify part is the thrown exception.  This changes the behavior of the driver when certain driver methods are called and there is a prompt/alert that is open.  It will check for this first...  If you set it to DISMISS, it will simply DISMISS the prompt before doing the action.  You can also set it to IGNORE and handle the prompt yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by looking through the `capabilities.js` file in the `selenium-webdriver` folder within `node-modules`.

I can set it to dismiss alerts automatically but setting the option:

```
options.setAlertBehavior('dismiss');
```

Eg:

```
let options = new firefox.Options();
    options.setPreference('geo.enabled', false);
    options.setAlertBehavior('dismiss');

const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();
```